# Implementation of string::find_first_of

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, stl

My confusion comes from a solution for `problem 792. Number of Matching Subsequences` in leetcode, the naive solution is to check all characters in S for each searching word.
The time complexity is too high to pass all test cases as outlined in the official answer.

The first code piece listed below could beats 100% merely because it calls `string::find_first_of`  function, while my hand written codes uses exactly the same routine(I believe) get TLE as expected.

So, why the first one is so fast?

```cpp
// comes from the second solution post in leetcode-cn
class Solution {
public:
    int numMatchingSubseq(string S, vector<string>& words) {
        int res = 0, j;
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i ++) {
            int position = -1;
            for (j = 0; j < words[i].size(); j ++) {
                position = S.find_first_of(words[i][j], position + 1); 
                if (position == -1) break; 
            }
            if (j == words[i].length()) res ++; 
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

version 2 hand written Time limit exceed

```cpp
static inline int find_first_of(const string & s, char & c, int st) {
    int  n = s.size() - st;
    const char * data = s.data(), * cur = data + st;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (cur[i] == c)
            return cur + i - data;
    }
    return -1;
}

class Solution {
public:
    int numMatchingSubseq(string S, vector<string>& words) {
        int res = 0, j;
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i ++) {
            int position = -1;
            for (j = 0; j < words[i].size(); j ++) {
                position = find_first_of(S, words[i][j], position + 1);
                if (position == -1) break; 
            }
            if (j == words[i].length()) res ++; 
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

Comment: The complexity of `string::find_first_of` is unspecified.

Comment: Though it's unspecified, i think it most likely to be O(n)

Comment: It's possible that the standard library implementation is using a highly-optimized function like `memchr` instead of a naive `for` in the inner loop. You would need to know the specific C++ compiler and standard library to investigate why it's faster.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Leetcode says they use g++17